# How to set up Dart debugging in WebStorm?

Tags: debugging, dart, breakpoints, webstorm

I am using **IntelliJ WebStorm** to develop an application in **Dart** and I'd like to use the debugging functionality, namely the capability to use breakpoints and in process evaluation.

How do I set it up in the IDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple steps that need to be completed to be able to use debugging features:

1. **Install Dartium on your development machine** This is a special browser based on Chromium which has the Dart VirtualMachine built in. If you installed the whole dev-pack from DartLang you probably already have it, otherwise you can find the download link on [www.dartlang.com/tools/download.html](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/download.html).
2. **Set up WebStorm to use Dartium** Once installed, add Dartium as an browser to WebStorm. In WebStorm click on *File > Settings > Browsers* then the green plus icon on the right and navigate to the chrome.exe executable in the Dartium folder.
3. **Set up Javascript debugger in WebStorm** In *File > Settings > Debugger > Javascript* set the built in server port to a port above 50000, I use 60666 for example.
4. ***Install the JetBrains IDE Support*** extension in Dartium Download the extension [here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji)
5. **Set up the port in the IDE support extension** Either right click on the **JB** extension logo and choose *Options*, or copy and paste this url

> chrome-extension://hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji/options.html

to your address bar and set the port to the one you chose in previous step *for example 60666*

And there you go, all is well, you are ready to go debugging ;)

**Just remember when you create *run/debug* configuration to choose Dartium as your browser of choice!**